# Return arrays within subarrays by length of greater than or less than 3 using filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, sub-array

Hi I'm trying to implement the array filter property to sort out subarrays that are greater than and less than 3 with two seperate functions.  I'm at a loss in terms of getting any further in correcting my functions.  Could someone help and please explain why I'm getting the current results.

```
var subarrays = [
    [1,2,3],
    ['a','b','c','d','e'],
    ['hippopatamus', 'zebra', 'crocodile','lion'],
    [false, 2]
];

var greaterThan3 = function(array){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){
        if(array[i].length > 3) {
            return array[i];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

var lessThan3 = function(array){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){
        if(array[i].length < 3){
            arr.push(array[i]);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return arr;
};
```

When I return greater than, only the animal names show up.  It seems that the length only refers to the length of the words and not the length of the array itself.  How do I target the length of the array.  With the less than I only get the single letters.  Again I'm looking at the length of the array itself and not it's contents.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are only getting animals is because, if you are not pushing the results of your greater than function into a different array, then since the last sub-array is the animals array, it is always returning you the animal sub-array.

var subarrays = [[1,2,3], ['a','b','c','d','e'], ['hippopatamus', 'zebra', 'crocodile','lion'], [false, 2]];

You can use the `forEach` function of the `array` to iterate over the subarrays.

```
var greaterArray = [];

subarrays.forEach(function(subArray){

if(subArray.length>3)
{
greaterArray.push(subArray);
}
});
```

Or

You can use the `filter` method also to achieve it more cleanly

```
subArrays.filter(function(subArray)
{
return subArray.length>3;
});
```

The `filter` method accepts `truthy` or `falsy` value and based upon that, it creates a new `array` internally, and with the `truthy` values and returns the new `array`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter only the arrays with length > 3 from subarrays you can use the built in filter:
    `subarrays.filter(function(a) { return a.length > 3; })`

If you want to see how filter is implemented see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to implement the array filter property

Not sure if you are looking to add a function to the prototype.

If it is so then you can do like this.

> greater than and less than 3

You can use `forEach` and check the length of each array

```
 var subarrays = [[1,2,3], ['a','b','c','d','e'], ['hippopatamus', 'zebra', 'crocodile','lion'], [false, 2]];
Array.prototype.sub3 = function(array){
var _newArray=[];
subarrays.forEach(function(item){
   if(item.length !==3){
 _newArray.push(item)
}
})
return _newArray
}
console.log(subarrays.sub3())
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/L53s1tt4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
var subarrays = [[1,2,3], ['a','b','c','d','e'], ['hippopatamus', 'zebra', 'crocodile','lion'], [false, 2]];


var lessThan3 = function(arr) {
   return arr.filter(function(a) {
     return a.length < 3
   })
}

var greaterThan3 = function(arr) {
   return arr.filter(function(a) {
     return a.length > 3
   })
}
```